# spark jdbc df limit... what is it doing?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to learn how to get a feel of what is going on inside Spark, and here's my current confusion.  I'm trying to read first 200 rows from an Oracle table into Spark:

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:...",
  "dbtable" -> "schema.table",
  "fetchSize" -> "5000",
  "partitionColumn" -> "my_row_id",
  "numPartitions" -> "16",
  "lowerBound" -> "0",
  "upperBound" -> "9999999"
  )).load()

jdbcDF.limit(200).count()
```

This, I would expect, to be fairly quick.  Similar action on a table with 500K rows completes in a reasonable time.  In this particular case, the table is much bigger (hundreds of millions of rows), but limit(200) would, I'd think, make it fast?  How do I go about figuring out where it spending its time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a matter of fact, spark isn't capable yet of pushing down the `limit` predicate.

So actually what's happening in this case scenario is that it's pulling all the data to spark and then limit and count. What you would need is to use it in a subquery as a table argument.

e.g :

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:...",
  "dbtable" -> "(select * from schema.table limit 200) as t",
  "fetchSize" -> "5000",
  "partitionColumn" -> "my_row_id",
  "numPartitions" -> "16",
  "lowerBound" -> "0",
  "upperBound" -> "9999999"
  )).load()
```

So mainly where it is spending time is pull all the data to spark.

You can also pass the limit dynamically in the subquery:

```
val n : Int = ???

val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:...",
  "dbtable" -> s"(select * from schema.table limit $n) as t",
  "fetchSize" -> "5000",
  "partitionColumn" -> "my_row_id",
  "numPartitions" -> "16",
  "lowerBound" -> "0",
  "upperBound" -> "9999999"
  )).load()
```

<s>There is a [JIRA ticket (SPARK-10899)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10899) *in progress* to solve this issue but it's been hanging for almost a year.</s>

**EDIT:** As the issue in the JIRA above was flagged as duplicate. You can continue on tracking the issue [here - SPARK-12126](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12126).
I hope that this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, it answers the substantial part (and it makes sense... how is Spark supposed to know how to limit results in a particular RDBMS?).

Comment: To be honest I haven't looked deeper into this topic but I know that it has to be implemented in the data source catalyst. But the Catalyst API is still mysterious and there is not much documentation around it. So I'm afraid I can't answer the question about how concretely the predicate should be push down.

Comment: As of **Nov 2017**, I can confirm that `Spark 2.2.0` is now able to push down the `limit` *predicate* to `MySQL`

Comment: I achieve this by including `limit` *clause* in the `SQL` *query* (string) itself. Not sure if if works the way it is mentioned here.

Comment: It is not the same thing @y2k-shubham :) We are talking about the predicate that you define on spark's side.