# Converting mysql table to spark dataset is very slow compared to same from csv file

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, amazon-s3

I have csv file in Amazon s3 with is 62mb in size (114 000 rows). I am converting it into spark dataset, and taking first 500 rows from it. Code is as follow;

```
DataFrameReader df = new DataFrameReader(spark).format("csv").option("header", true);
Dataset<Row> set=df.load("s3n://"+this.accessId.replace("\"", "")+":"+this.accessToken.replace("\"", "")+"@"+this.bucketName.replace("\"", "")+"/"+this.filePath.replace("\"", "")+"");

 set.take(500)
```

The whole operation takes 20 to 30 sec.

Now I am trying the same but rather using csv I am using mySQL table with 119 000 rows. MySQL server is in amazon ec2. Code is as follow;

```
String url ="jdbc:mysql://"+this.hostName+":3306/"+this.dataBaseName+"?user="+this.userName+"&password="+this.password;

SparkSession spark=StartSpark.getSparkSession();

SQLContext sc = spark.sqlContext();

DataFrameReader df = new DataFrameReader(spark).format("csv").option("header", true);
Dataset<Row> set = sc
            .read()
            .option("url", url)
            .option("dbtable", this.tableName)
            .option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
            .format("jdbc")
            .load();
set.take(500);
```

This is taking 5 to 10 minutes. 
I am running spark inside jvm. Using same configuration in both cases.

**I can use partitionColumn,numParttition etc but I don't have any numeric column and one more issue is the schema of the table is unknown to me.**

My issue is not how to decrease the required time as I know in ideal case spark will run in cluster but what I can not understand is why this big time difference in the above two case?

Comment: Is the line `DataFrameReader df = new DataFrameReader(spark).format("csv").option("header", true);` really necessary?

Comment: No it is not necessary at all, I was testing something else, forget to remove

Answer (score 10):

This problem has been covered multiple times on StackOverflow:

- [How to improve performance for slow Spark jobs using DataFrame and JDBC connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32188295)
- [spark jdbc df limit... what is it doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39836279)
- [How to use JDBC source to write and read data in (Py)Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30983982)

and in external sources:

- https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/05_spark_sql_and_dataset_api.md#parallelizing-reads

so just to reiterate - by default `DataFrameReader.jdbc` doesn't distribute data or reads. It uses single thread, single exectuor.

To distribute reads:

- use ranges with `lowerBound` / `upperBound`:

  ```
  Properties properties;
  Lower

  Dataset<Row> set = sc
      .read()
      .option("partitionColumn", "foo")
      .option("numPartitions", "3")
      .option("lowerBound", 0)
      .option("upperBound", 30)
      .option("url", url)
      .option("dbtable", this.tableName)
      .option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
      .format("jdbc")
      .load();
  ```
- `predicates`

  ```
  Properties properties;
  Dataset<Row> set = sc
      .read()
      .jdbc(
          url, this.tableName,
          {"foo < 10", "foo BETWWEN 10 and 20", "foo > 20"},
          properties
      )
  ```

Comment: I'm trying to read `MySQL` table having 500M rows with `numPartitions=32`. Still the reading using `Spark` is much slower than [`sqoop`](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism) (also with 32 tasks). I even tried setting `fetchsize` to higher value (1k or 10k) but no gain. I'm using standard `Connector/J v5.1.41`  and I'm on `MySQL v5.6`.

Comment: is there a way to improve parallelism in spark 2.4 for jdbc reader?

Answer (score -2):

## Please follow the steps below

1.download a copy of the JDBC connector for mysql. I believe you already have one.

```
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar
```

2.create a db-properties.flat file in the below format

```
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort}/${jdbcDatabase}
user=<username>
password=<password>
```

3.create a empty table first where you want to load the data.

## invoke spark shell with driver class

```
spark-shell --driver-class-path  <your path to mysql jar>
```

## then import all the required package

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream}
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
```

## initiate a hive context or a sql context

```
val sQLContext = new HiveContext(sc)
import sQLContext.implicits._
import sQLContext.sql
```

## set some of the properties

```
sQLContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
sQLContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
```

## Load mysql db properties from file

```
val dbProperties = new Properties()
dbProperties.load(new FileInputStream(new File("your_path_to/db-        properties.flat")))
val jdbcurl = dbProperties.getProperty("jdbcUrl")
```

## create a query to read the data from your table and pass it to read method of #sqlcontext. this is where you can manage your where clause

```
val df1 = "(SELECT  * FROM your_table_name) as s1"
```

## pass the jdbcurl, select query and db properties to read method

```
val df2 = sQLContext.read.jdbc(jdbcurl, df1, dbProperties)
```

## write it to your table

```
df2.write.format("orc").partitionBy("your_partition_column_name").mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("your_target_table_name")
```

Comment: What have you done differently that you think would solve the asked question, i.e. **slow reading of `MySQL` *table* into `DataFrame`**? Can you point out a mistake / inefficiency in the *code snippets* provided in the question that is improved in some way by the *snippets* provided by you?