# Does Spark Dataframe aplies the transformations against DB?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I get a table with PySpark

```py
df1 = session.read.jdbc(url=self.url,
                        table=self.table,
                        properties={"driver": self.driver,
                                    "user": self.user,
                                    "password": self.password})
```

or

```py
df1 = sql.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
                .options(url=self.url, 
                        query=self.table,
                        user=self.user,
                        password=self.password,
                        tempdir="s3://path/data/").load()
```

and then I apply some transformations like joins and groupBy

```py
df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id)
df_res = df3.groupBy("id").agg({'tax': 'sum'})
```

is that done against the DB?
If yes, what is the way to do that in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. While Spark can push down simple projections and selections (details depend on a particular data source implementation) it doesn't apply heavy processing against database, unless it is explicitly instructed to in a supported data source.

For example with `jdbc` you pass a [subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38729436/6910411)  as the `table` argument, and with `com.databricks.spark.redshift` you can use `query` option.

With the first snippet (`jdbc`) Spark will read all the required data (after applying possible projections and selections) using [a single executor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42696455/6910411), in the second snippet the result of the initial `query` (plus projections and selections) to S3 and read it from there in parallel. In both cases Spark should be able to push down projection `(id, tax)`.

After that Spark will process data locally inside the cluster, this includes `join` and aggregation.